# Dagger .dot file not generated

Tags: android, dagger

I'm using `Dagger` for dependency injection and the app is running working fine, but I wanted to use `GraphViz` to take a look at the generated graph but I'm unable to find the generated `.dot` file.

I've searched everywhere inside my project folder (`find . -name '*.dot'`) but it's nowhere to be found.

Any ideas how to get access to this file? Thanks.